# Traverse the DOM to passback an image

Tags: javascript, dom

Ok so I want to click on the image '.escape' and passback the source of the image '.myimg2' onclick.
Below is my attempt at doing this:
I know it is just traversing the DOM but I don't know how to traverse the DOM very well.
Thanks for any enlightenment.

```
<table class="table2">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="info2" ondragstart="return false" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="drop(event)" >
                <div  style="float:left">
                    <img class="myimg2" style="max-height:80px;" src="Pictures/QuestionMark.png">
                </div>
                <div style="float:left;">
                    <p class="myname2">Name: Unspecified</p>
                    <p class="myprof2">Profession: Unspecified</p>
                </div>
                <img class="escape" onclick="returnDrop(this.parentNode.childNode[0].src)" style="max-height:8px;" src="Pictures/escape.png">
            </div>
        </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what do you mean by " I want to click on the image '#escape' and passback the source of the image '#myimg2' onclick" ?

Comment: @TilwinJoy When I click on the image '#escape', I want to get the source of the image shown here under class '#myimg2' and use that image source location in a javascript function. Hopefully this is more clear

Comment: You're mixing up '#id' and '.class', which may confuse people. You might want to edit your question.

Comment: @jcaron Someone beat me to it lol, thanks for the tip though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('myimg2')[0]
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ENQFX/

Comment: Thankyou, I'll select this answer as correct after the 6 minute grace period :)

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about IDs (`#escape`) but you're using classes (`.escape`). You should switch your class attributes to IDs because they're unique. Here I'll use the class though. You should put this in your `onclick=` attribute inside `.escape`.

```
this.setAttribute('src',this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('myimg2')[0].getAttribute('src'))
```

Here we set the the `src` attribute to be that of the first `.myimg2` class element that is inside `.escape`'s parent element. If there are no other elements with the class `.myimg2` you could use `document.get...` instead of `this.parentNode.get...`.

With IDs instead of classes:

```
this.setAttribute('src',document.getElementById('myimg2').getAttribute('src'))
```

Note that with IDs you don't have to specify the parent node because IDs are unique to the element through the entire document.